# How to insert unique values without id

Tags: mysql, insert

I would like to insert in my tables ROLES values if it does not exist yet, without using the id

My table ROLES (id, name)
Entries : 'admin', 'superadmin'

Could you please give me an example for MySQL?

I and to Insert the value in name only if this name is not already present in the table

ie. :

- INSERT INTO ROLES (name) VALUES ('noadmin') should work
- INSERT INTO ROLES (name) VALUES ('admin') should not work

Late info

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS roles ( 
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: provide more detail in your question

Comment: If you want to block duplicates create a unique key on name or test it in a trigger, if you don't want to provide an id you don't have to if the data type allows null , if you want id to be generated either make it auto_increment (if it's int) or build your own id in a trigger.

Comment: where does new name and id come from? a table or ??

Answer (score 0):

The `id` column is optional if it is an autoincrement / primary key

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `roles` VALUES ('admin');
INSERT IGNORE INTO `roles` VALUES ('superadmin');
```

or

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `roles` VALUES ('admin'), ('superadmin');
```

The INSERT IGNORE statement will cause MySQL to do nothing when the insertion throws an error. If there’s no error, then a new row will be added to the table.

You should have a UNIQUE key constraint set on roles `name` column to prevent duplicates.

Comment: I updated my answer with IGNORE statement

Comment: No, when I INSERT IGNORE, the value is still inserted

Comment: You should have a UNIQUE key constraint set on role name column.

Comment: @Valeriu Ciuca that's not a valid value clause - VALUES ('admin'), ('superadmin'); is

Comment: @Tnecniv you can have as many unique keys as you need , and they don't have to be single column..

Comment: @P.Salmon, my bad, edited the answer with ('value1'), ('value2'), Thx

Comment: @P.Salmon I havn't a unique KEY on my column name, you solve the problem. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Tnecniv: Rule of thumb: you must have at least one UNIQUE key constraint besides the primary key

Comment: @Tnecniv: The unique `name` constraint was already specified in the answer.